# PowerShell command to insert 1 character in the middle of a filename

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

Have a directory of images named like IMG_xxxx.JPG, where x is an integer. I need to insert a "1" after the underscore, so each name becomes IMG_1xxxx.JPG.

I tried this in PowerShell:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "_","_1" }
```

and it worked on a number of the files in my directory, however, it went crazy on some others, and tried to add a seemingly infinite loop of 1s to some of the filenames. Error message was:

> Rename-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   At line:1 char:7
>   + Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.name -replace "*","_1" }
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\michel...11111111109.JPG:String) [Rename-Item], PathTooLongExcepti
>     on
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Happy for an alternate approach here. Understanding what I actually did wrong is a secondary goal to getting this rename done! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the pipeline runs while `Get-ChildItem` is still enumerating the files. You should probably first enumerate all files, and then rename them, so that renamed files don't get picked up twice:

```
(dir) | rename-Item -new { $_.name -replace '_','_1' }
```

The parentheses ensure that `dir` is first evaluated completely and its result then passed through the rest of the pipeline. it's conceptually the same as

```
$files = dir
$files | rename-item ...
```

Another option would be to check whether you need to rename the file at all:

```
dir | where { $_.Name -match '_\d{4}\D' } | rename-item -NewName { ... }
```

Comment: That did it! Once I fixed your mistype of "rename" as "rename-item" that is, so corrected the line would be: (dir) | rename-item -new { $_.name -replace '_','_1' } ... Thanks a ton for the (quick) save.

Comment: Just tried it out here, noticed that `rename` isn't an alias and fixed that part in the answer. And also noticed that your problem doesn't seem to occur every time. Maybe depends a bit on the number of files in the folder.

Comment: 735, for whatever it's worth :D Thanks on behalf of future Googlers for alias fix.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.Substring(0,WHERE_TO_INSERT) + "STRING_TO_BE_INSERTED"  + $_.name.Substring(WHERE_TO_INSERT)}
```

You can use this one to insert whatever you want as a string inside the filename. Works on a whole folder.